# Implementing Interface on Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, interface, models

I have a Laravel 5 model *Account* which implements an `Interface`.

I have implemented all the methods of the `Interface` however when I run the code, Laravel complains that the Model does not implement the interface.

Error below

**Account.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Accounts\Models;

use Abc\Accounts\Contracts\Accountlnterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model implements Accountlnterface {
....
```

In my **Controller** I am doing this

```
$account = Account::where('something', 'value')->first();
```

This returns the model just fine.

The problem lies when I pass it into another class controller

```
$result = new Transaction($account, 5.00);
```

**Transaction file**

```
public function __construct(Accountlnterface $account, float $value = 0.00) 
{
    $this->account = $account;
```

The transaction constructor is looking for the Interface however laravel is complaining that Account does not implement it.

Im not sure whats wrong with this code.

Error from Laravel

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Abc....\Transaction::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Abc\Accounts\Components\Accountlnterface, instance of
>   Tymr\Plugins\Accounts\Models\Account given.

Directly after the model is loaded I ran this code

```
        if($account instanceof AccountInterface)
            echo "working";
        else
            echo "fails";
```

and it certainly fails.

Comment: Did you bind your AccountInterface to the Account in your service container? You need to direct Laravel on how to resolve an instance of your Interface ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a service container binding in one of your service providers or better create a new service provider.

It helps Laravel know the implementation to use for your interface.

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ModelsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
      public function register()
      {
         $this->app->bind(
            'Abc\Accounts\Contracts\Accountlnterface',
            'Abc\Accounts\Models\Account'
         );
      }
}
```

In `app/config/app.php`, register your service provider under the available providers.

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    'ModelsServiceProvider',
]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However when I write `if($account instanceof AccountInterface)` it still doesnt resolve. Is that expected ? But works for passing via constructor

Comment: ok, then thats strange because the binding worked and allows my Model to be passed in, however doesn't resolve with the instanceof condition.